# Angular - How to not use ngModel in FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

How not to use ngmodel for the FormArray? I'm trying to add my input fields but I'm using ngModel. Once you add row the value is passed to the next row.

> .TS

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id : [0],
      Status: ['', Validators.required],
      array: this.formBuilder.array([this.createList()])
    })

createList(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [0],
      QtyOrder : ['0', Validators.required],
      QtyDelivered : [''],
      QtyRejected : ['', Validators.required],
      QtyReceived : ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }

get array():FormArray{
return this.form.get('array') as FormArray;
}

Calculate(){
 let total = this.form.get('array') as FormArray;
 return total.controls.map((x) => x.get('QtyDelivered').value - x.get('QtyRejected').value).reduce((sum,amount) => sum + amount, 0);
}
```

> .HTML ----Here I want to put the total.---

```
<input type="text" formControlName="QtyReceived" [ngModel]="Calculate()">
```

Comment: The Calculate function is performed when you input QtyDelivered and QtyRejected, and then click the button?

Comment: Sorry i just added the ngModel, i don't have the button it automatically populate it.

Comment: Did you try `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly it's not working,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add events for when the `QtyDelivered` and `QtyRejected` controls are key in with value, it will trigger the `Calculate()` method.

```
<input formControlName="QtyDelivered" (input)="Calculate()" />

<input formControlName="QtyRejected" (input)="Calculate()" />
```

And modify the `Calculate` method to bind the calculated value to `QtyReceived` control.

```js
Calculate() {
  let total = this.form.get('array') as FormArray;

  total.controls[0]
    .get('QtyReceived')
    .patchValue(
      total.controls
        .map((x) => x.get('QtyDelivered').value - x.get('QtyRejected').value)
        .reduce((sum, amount) => sum + amount, 0)
    );
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v9ewsd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Note that you are performing the calculation for all FormGroup in FormArray, it is fine when you have only one FormGroup in FormArray, but if you are trying to perform the calculation for each row (when there is more than one FormGroup in FormArray), the calculation is incorrect.

---

In case you are performing the calculation by row, you need to specify the FormGroup to be used for calculation.

**Solution 1: Trigger with `(input)` event.**

```
<input formControlName="QtyDelivered" (input)="Calculate(i)" />

<input formControlName="QtyRejected" (input)="Calculate(i)" />
```

```js
Calculate(i) {
  let total = this.form.get('array') as FormArray;
  let formGroup = total.controls[i] as FormGroup;

  formGroup
    .get('QtyReceived')
    .patchValue(
      formGroup.get('QtyDelivered').value - formGroup.get('QtyRejected').value
    );
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo (Solution 1)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v9ewsd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

**Solution 2: Subscribe FormControl valueChanges event.**

```js
this.array.controls.forEach((g: FormGroup) => {
  g.get('QtyDelivered')
    .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe((x) => {
      g.get('QtyReceived').patchValue(this.Calculate(g));
    });

  g.get('QtyRejected')
    .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe((x) => {
      g.get('QtyReceived').patchValue(this.Calculate(g));
    });
});
```

```js
Calculate(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  return (
    formGroup.get('QtyDelivered').value - formGroup.get('QtyRejected').value
  );
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo (Solution 2)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxxnnb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Make sure that you have to unsubscribe the observable for `valueChanges` when the component is destroyed for better optimization.

Comment: its working, but how should i put to the other push row?

Comment: Hi @Yan, I had update the answer. Probably this is what you need.

Comment: the solution 1 is working anyways but the 2, i saw your using pipe do you know how to put a decimal in formarray?

Comment: Hi @YongShun I tried your solution 1 and its working. However I want to add validation that the QtyRejected should not exceed to the value of QtyDelivered.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, would be great to create another question for the new requirement for better readable.